# If $F$ is a free module then $-\otimes F$ is an exact functor

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

For any module $M$, the functor $-\otimes M $ is right exact. I want to show that if $F$ is a free module then $-\otimes F$ is a exact.

I could not see how to adapt the proof for the case of $M$ not being free to  this case.

Answer (score 0):

Given an exact sequence of $R$-modules
$$
0\to M'\to M\to M''\to 0
$$
the general result states that
$$
M'\otimes F\to M\otimes F\to M''\otimes F\to 0
$$
is exact. The only thing missing is to show that the first arrow here is injective.

Since $F$ is free, it's isomorphic to a direct sum $\bigoplus_I R$ over some index set $I$. And we have, for any $R$-module $N$, that
$$
N\otimes_R\left(\bigoplus_I R\right)\cong \bigoplus_I N
$$
So, what we are really after is this: If $M'\to M$ is an injective map, is the induced componentwise map $\bigoplus_I M'\to\bigoplus_I M$ injective? And it clearly is, giving us our result.

Comment: The isomorphism $N\otimes_R\left(\bigoplus R\right)\cong \bigoplus N$ is not enough. It has to be natural in order to conclude that it is enough to look at direct products of maps. Is it natural?

Comment: @freakish You _could_ do basically the same argument without appealing to that isomorphism at all, just typing out the general form of the elements in the tensor product. It's not very pretty, and night take some time. Would you have liked it if I did that instead?